# How to change gcloud auth according to the directories

Tags: gcloud

I have two projects using GCP with different google accounts.

```
$ gcloud auth list
    Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        example1@gmail.com
*       example2@gmail.com
```

Currently, I'm using `gcloud config set account` command every time I change my projects. It's a bit annoying.

Is there a way to automatically change google account when I change directory like `nodenv` or `rbenv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking into the possibility of using a background script such as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do

    case $(pwd) in 
"/home/dir1") 
gcloud config set account user1@test.com
echo “changed to user 1”;;
"/home/dir2") 
gcloud config set account user2@test.com
echo “changed to user 2”;;

esac
    sleep 100
done
```

then `chmod +x my_script.sh` and run using disown to be sent to the background

```
./my_script.sh & disown
```

However, the best approach here would be using aliases

for example:

```
alias cd1='cd ~/dir1; echo "changing to dir1"; gcloud config set account user1@test.com'
alias cd2='cd ~/dir1; echo "changing to dir2"; gcloud config set account user2@test.com'
```

this way you can use commands **cd1** and **cd2** to change directory and set the matching user

Answer (score 4):

You can create multiple configurations and then automate configuration switching.

[Managing SDK Configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations)

> A configuration is a named set of SDK properties. These properties are
>   key-value pairs that govern the behavior of the gcloud command-line
>   tool and other SDK tools.
>
> To help make changing configurations seamless, you can leverage tools
>   such as **direnv** and **ondir** to automatically switch between
>   configurations when you switch working directories. One way of
>   accomplishing this would be to set the necessary environment variables
>   (like CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME) in the .envrc file in the root
>   directory of your project.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thanks!

Minor feedback but you could link directly to the section you're talking about: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations#automating_configuration_switching